# Adding "-" to .htaccess url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)-pid-(.*)\.html$ product.php?n=$1&pid=$2
```

and in my php file i have this code:

```
<?php print $product->name; ?>-pid-<?php print $product[id]; ?>.html
```

How can I automatically add "-" to the product name so it does not look like this "Apple iPod 32GB 1st generation" but to look like this "Apple-iPod-32GB-1st-generation"

Thanks

Comment: Be aware that there are other possible product name characters that you do not want showing up in a URL.  For quick and easy: consider running urlencode() in addition to replacing the spaces with dashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$seourl = strtolower(urlencode($product->name));
```

It uses + and not -, but a str_replace could change that if you insist.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace spaces with dashes it in PHP.

```
<?php print str_replace(" ", "-", $product->name) ?>-pid-<?php print $product[id]; ?>.html
```

Answer (score 0):

use **str_replace()** function.

Just replace the spaces with hypen using this function.

```
str_replace(" ","-",$productname)
```